# Identify tenant url in multi-tenant web application

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, url, multi-tenant

Can someone help me identify a tenant's url in my multi-tenant web application? Right now my app is hosted on AWS at `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:xxx`. Each tenant accesses the app by going to `app.some_client_domain.com` which gets forwarded with masking to my AWS instance. Things I have tried so far:

1) Attach `window.location.href` to the http headers & print it on the server side (Node.js):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/something',
    headers: {
        'tenant_url': window.location.href
    },
    success: function() {

    }, error: function() {

    }
})
```

This technique returns my AWS server's IP address xx.xxx.xxx.xxx.

2) Attach window.location.hostname to the http headers & print it on the server side (Node.js):

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '/ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com/api/something',
    headers: {
        'tenant_url': window.location.hostname
    },
    success: function() {

    }, error: function() {

    }
})
```

This technique returns `ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com`

What I NEED to return is `app.client_domain.com` so I can identify which tenant is making the request.

Misc.

On the server side, I also tried logging out the entire HTTP request and did a search for anything that resembles `app.some_client_domain.com` but there were not any matches.

Can someone help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried logging all HTTP headers on your server to see what is available already? I'd be surprised if this wasn't available in the request already. It sounds like your "forwarded with masking" setup may be stripping the domain name? Can you describe that setup more?

Comment: Hi - Yes, I tried logging the entire HTTP request but there wasn't anything that I needed. The setup is in GoDaddy, I added a subdomain called `app` to `www.client_domain.com`. So whenever someone hits `app.client_domain.com`, they get forwarded to my AWS instance @MarkB

Comment: It looks like Godaddy basically wraps your application in a frame to perform the "masking". This sounds like a terrible idea to me. It is going to prevent your site from seeing the actual requested domain (as you are encountering) and it really ins't providing any added security. If you truly want to hide your back-end IP address from your end users while still being able to do things like determine the domain the user requested, I would recommend using Cloudflare.